# How can I save extension information to a text file?

Tags: url, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

pretty much just the title. I'm developing a chrome extension that can read the current pages URL on button click. The issue I've run into is saving that URL to a text file that is on my host computer. This extension is for my personal use so I have already tried to use Native Messaging but that doesn't seem to do anything for saving info to existing files. Is there anything I've missed?

I tried to use Native messaging but don't have quite a firm grasp on it just yet so I can't save any info to my host computer. Another idea I had was saving the URL to my clipboard and then having a native host paste the clipboard info to a text file but again, didn't work. Or at least I couldn't find anything for it.

I'm  still very much a newbie to programming in general so any help, no matter how basic, is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Mozilla > Add-ons > Browser Extensions > Working with files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Working_with_files) Applies to Chrome, too.

Comment: [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) is not available in Service Workers due to its potential to create memory leaks. But you can use [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) instead.

Comment: Extensions run in a sandbox so they won't be able to directly write to your file system or specified path. You can easily achieve what you are trying to do using native messaging host. That's the only option that I see right now

Comment: When you say "my host computer", do you mean your PC ?

Comment: @NorioYamamoto yes it's my PC

Comment: @Asesh I wanted to use native messaging host but I couldn't figure out how to save the text to a local file

Answer (score 1):

This sample is for **Windows**.
This creates **C:\work\url.txt** on icon click.
**url_to_file.reg** depends on the development folder **C:\Users\norio\url_to_file**, so you need to rewrite it according to your environment.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "url_to_file",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
  const application = "url_to_file";
  const port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(application);
  port.postMessage(tabs[0].url);
});
```

url_to_file.json

```json
{
  "name": "url_to_file",
  "description": "Deleting this key will result in an error.",
  "path": "url_to_file.py",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://<your extension id>/"
  ]
}
```

url_to_file.py

```py
import sys
import json
import struct

def getMessage():
    rawLength = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)
    messageLength = struct.unpack("@I", rawLength)[0]
    message = sys.stdin.buffer.read(messageLength).decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(message)

while True:
    receivedMessage = getMessage()
    with open("c:\\work\\url.txt", "w") as o:
        o.write(receivedMessage)
```

url_to_file.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\url_to_file]
@="C:\\Users\\norio\\url_to_file\\url_to_file.json"
```

**Note:**
To execute this sample, Python must be able to be invoked with cmd.

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help and code, it really was helpful. I've now run into an additional problem though. When I click on the popup it opens a python console but doesn't run the python program from url_to_file.py Any idea how I may fix this?

Comment: @SebastianCoder, The url_to_file.py runs in the background so it shouldn't open the console. I have edited the answer, please check.

Comment: I am able to invoke python with cmd as you said in your edit but it still seems to be opening a python console when I open the extension. Another issue I found is that the python console is opened when I click on the extension, not the pop-up. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I looked at your tutorial, while it did help me. My python console still opens whenever I click on the extension. I've tried looking at your code from the video but am not yet at the level to understand it completely. I have written my code exactly as you have in your original answer.